# Android Things: How to install apk from device with pm install -r

Tags: java, android, android-things

I am trying to build an auto-updater for the Android Things `app.apk`. So far I have downloaded the new version of the `.apk` into the `/sdcard/download/app.apk` and I can also install it from there via the adb terminal e.g.

```
adb shell
pm install -r /sdcard/Download/app
```

Now I try to do the same via the device itself. Currently I have this

```
Process install = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pm install -r /sdcard/Download/app");
install.waitFor();
```

But nothing happens. I tried to also open the shell like this, but this time I am getting `Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied`

```
 Process install = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
 DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(install.getOutputStream());
 out.writeBytes("pm install -r /sdcard/Download/app");
 out.flush();
```

Is it possible at all to install the downloaded apk from the device itself? [The general way with `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` doesn't work either.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically) It blanks out and that's it. Nothing happens.

Comment: I know a way to install an apk but it needs a user to accept and install it.
I can share it if you want

Comment: Why you didn't use [OTA UPDATES](https://developer.android.com/things/console/update.html)?

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Because they take 5 hours. At least the documentation says so...

Comment: @Blundell Since there is only one apk running it's not feasible to wait several hours to provide a patch or hotfix.

Comment: "It checks for new versions every 5 hours." - it's not update time. " it can take several hours for all devices to be updated." - may be for you device quantity it not take "several hours".

Comment: @Onik I had the app opened and replace installed it over the adb terminal. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use ADB command

```
adb install /path-of-your-apk/app.apk
```

Comment: I am not using the adb terminal. I am on the device itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily launch an install prompt:

```
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    .setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///path/to/your.apk"), 
                    "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(promptInstall);
```

However, you cannot install `.apks` without user's explicit permission. Not unless the device and your program are rooted.

Comment: I tried many variations of these, but the Install Wizard never opens. It works fine on non Android Things devices.